# How to get the process running in the task manager using Install Shield

Tags: installshield, uninstallation

I am very new to Installsheild and it is programming. We have an application which run using MMC.exe. during uninstallation we need to check whther the app is running if yes then need to close the app. if user runs the app there is process mmc.exe running in the task manager.
how can i check whthere MMC.exe is running in the task manager

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232703/taskkill-exe-dont-throw-an-error-if-the-process-is-not-running) question:

Put this code in a batch and run it during uninstall. If yours is an msi project then you can put this in a custom action, if its a installscript project, then put this in onmaintui function.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mmc.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mmc.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im mmc.exe
```